# what linker use for assembler

Tags: assembly, gcc, linker, ld

I am using the `ld` as linker for my assembler code but there are `gcc` too and I don't known What linker I should use. What is diference betwen `gcc` or `ld`. I known the `gcc` isn't only linker but c++ or c compiler.
I don't find any information about that.

Comment: `gcc` invokes `ld` for you. It's still the same linker. You can use `-v` option to see how it does that.

Comment: gcc is a compiler, as is the assembler, ld is the linker, that is the gnu toolchain.  gcc knows where it was executed from and as a result knows where the C and other libraries are.  ld does not you have to explicitly tell ld where everything is (if you have any libraries or other to link).  See the ld command line that gcc generates.

Comment: for assembly language you only need as and ld which are part of the binutils package.

Comment: Technically `cc1` is the C compiler.